# EmEditorで結合処理無しで実質的に結合したように開くことはできますでしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
https://jp.emeditor.com/forums/topic/%E5%A4%A7%E9%87%8F%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E6%9C%AC%E5%8C%96/

この質問よりさらに単純にした開き方で実質的な結合のような開き方が出来ますでしょうか？という質問です。

事例
北海道旅行01.csv
北海道旅行02.csv
北海道旅行03.csv
北海道旅行04.csv

EmEditorでファイル結合の処理が出来るのは上の質問でわかったのですが、単純にこのような複数のファイルをEmEditorに一括ドラッグ＆ドロップするだけで、01～04までをまとめた文章として開くことはできませんでしょうか？
現在だとそのままドラッグ＆ドロップすると4つの画面で個々に開きますが、

01～04のファイルの文字をひとつの画面で順番に繋げて開くということです。
たとえばshiftキーを押しながらドラッグ＆ドロップすると結合した文章で開くとかできたら良いです。

実質的に開くだけでファイル結合が出来たように開けるという機能です。
保存はしてないで結合という言い方とは違うかも知れませんが、文章がくっついた状態でひとつのつながった文章として開けるという機能です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「質問が解決しました」という情報は質問の本文に追記してしまうのではなく、役に立った回答に対してコメントを付けてください。質問の編集はあくまで **質問の明確化** にのみ使用されるべきです。(いったんロールバックさせてもらいました)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイルを結合して開くマクロ

# connect.jsee

```js
#title = "連番結合"

function regPat( re, pat ){ // EmEditor の Regex のパラメータ設定で Javascript の RegExp を使う
    if( pat instanceof RegExp ){
        var m = String( pat ).match( /^\/(.*)\/([igo]*)$/ );
        re.Pattern = m[1];
        re.Global = /g/.test( m[2] );
        re.OnlyWord = /o/.test( m[2] );
        re.IgnoreCase = /i/.test( m[2] );
        // re.SeparateCrLf = /s/.test( m[2] );
    } else { // ? String
        re.Pattern = pat;
    }
    return re;
}

    var title = regPat( editor.regex, /.*\\(.*?)$/ ).Find( document.Path ); // ShiftJIS 対策に、Emeditorの regexを使う。
    title = (title == null)? "" : title.Item(1).Value;

    var strName = document.Name;
    var baseName = strName.match( /^(.*)\.(.*?)$/ );
    if( baseName == null ){ baseName = [ strName, "" ]; }
    var numMatch = baseName[1].match( /^(.*?)(\d+)([^\d]*?)$/ );    // ファイル名末尾の数字
    if( numMatch == null || numMatch.length != 4 )  Quit();

    var num = 1 * numMatch[2];
    var connectList = [ "\"" + strName + "\"" ];
    var FSO = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
    var lastNum = "";
    while( true ){
        num += 1;
        var str = String( num );
        for( i = numMatch[2].length - str.length; i > 0; -- i ){ str = "0" + str; }

        var filePath = numMatch[1] + str + numMatch[3] + "." + baseName[2];
        if( ! FSO.FileExists( document.Path + "\\" + filePath ) )   break;
        lastNum = str;
        connectList.push( "\"" + filePath + "\"" );
    }
    if( connectList.length <= 1 ){
        alert( "連番の結合対象がありませんでした。 '" + filePath + "'" );
        Quit();
    }
//  connectPath = title + numMatch[1] + numMatch[2] + "-" + lastNum + numMatch[3] + "結合." + baseName[2];
    connectPath = title + baseName[1] + "結合." + baseName[2];
// 上の行をコメントアウトしてその上の行を有効にすれば、結合ファイル名のフォーマットは [開始番号]-[終了番号] になる。
//  comStr = "copy /b /y " + connectList.join("+") + " \"" + connectPath + "\" & emeditor \"" + connectPath + "\"";
//  (new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" )).Run( "cmd /C " + comStr );

    var tmpBat = document.Path + "\\__temp_" + ProcessID + "_.bat";

    var fs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    fs.type = 2;
    fs.charset = "utf-8";
    fs.open();
    fs.WriteText( "@Echo off & chcp 65001\r\n\r\ncd /d \"" + document.Path + "\"\r\n\r\n" );
    fs.WriteText( "copy /b /y " + connectList[0] + " + " + connectList[1] + " \"" + connectPath + "\"\r\n" );
    for( var i = 2; i < connectList.length; ++ i ){
        fs.WriteText( "copy /b /y \"" + connectPath + "\" + " + connectList[i] + " \"" + connectPath + "\"\r\n" );
    }
    fs.WriteText( "\r\nstart \"\" /MIN emeditor \"" +  connectPath + "\"\r\n" );
    fs.WriteText( "del \"%~0\"\r\n" );

    fs.Position = 0;
    fs.Type = 1;    // binmode
    fs.Position = 3;    // BOM skip
    var bytes = fs.Read();
    fs.Position = 0;
    fs.SetEOS();
    fs.Write( bytes );

    fs.SaveToFile( tmpBat, 2 );
    fs.Close();

    (new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" )).Run( tmpBat );
```

2021/03/26 更新

- 長いパス名対策
  バッチファイル化とカレントパスへの相対化
- 多数の結合ファイル対策
  copy コマンドを 1ファイル毎に分割

Comment: ありがとうございます！これは感動の素晴らしく理想的な動作です。素晴らしいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: お世話になっております。baseName[1] + "結合." + baseName[2] のところに一番先頭に親フォルダのフォルダ名を付加するのは可能でしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。フォルダ名が福岡旅行で、ファイル名が博多001.txtだと福岡旅行博多001結合.txtみたいな感じです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 差し替えてみました。

Comment: お世話になっております。ありがとうございます。一発で数工程が瞬時に完結できてます。
いろいろやってみますと、同じ拡張子の同様の連番の付き方も同じタイプのテキストファイル、同じエンコードタイプでも、マクロが動くファイルと、動かないファイルがありました。同様に連番なのですが、「指定したファイルは存在しません。新規作成しますか」と確認画面が出て動作しないものが半数ある感じです。動作しないのは、原因は何か不明なんですが、いろいろやってみます。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: connectPath を "" で囲ってなかったのが原因だと思います、パスに空白が含まれると誤作動してしまいます。最後の方の comStr = ... の一行修正で上手くいくはずです。

Comment: 教えていただき、ありがとうございます。やってみました。現在でている状態のものでパスに空白があっても関係なく動作しました。connectPath を "" をつけると空ファイルが出来て動作しませんでした。いろいろ動作させてみたところ、現在でいるコードは、フォルダ階層が浅いところでしか動作しないようです。たとえば、Cドライブ→ダウンロードフォルダ→会議の資料→沖縄の件、みたいに階層が深いフォルダにあるテキストファイルだと反応しませんでした。階層の浅いところに持ってくると動きます。何が考えられますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 動作する階層でも、ファイル数が100個とか多くなると動かないようです。その場合は結合するファイル数を減らすか、浅いフォルダ階層に移し替えて動作させると結合できました。動かない場合は反応無しの状態です。

Comment: ファイル数が少ない場合だと、深い階層にしても動作しました。100個くらいのファイル数になると階層が浅くないと動作しないようです。ファイル数の多い連番サンプルを用意しました。よろしくお願いいたします。https://drive.google.com/file/d/191CZveQbe8dTENF2yotYMh64ORc62-QG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: お世話になっております。いろいろ試していると、入っている中身はそのままで、フォルダ名の長さを変えるだけで、結合できるのと、反応無しのパターンになることがわかりました。これだと動かない　wepppsadsfdfs　このファイル名の長さだと動くweppp　パス名が長くなることに原因がありそうです。

Comment: また差し替えました。たぶん改善できたと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまく動いている感じです。何度も修正していただき、ご厚意に深謝しております。

Comment: 質問欄には、user40304さまの高い技術力によって問題が解決したことを更新させていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

マクロで実現するとすればこんな感じでしょうか、自動と手動前・後の 3パターンです。

#### lljump.jsee

```js
#title = "前後の連番文書を開く"

/*

    カーソル位置が文頭か文末だったとき、
    アクティブな文書のファイル名最後の数字を増減させたファイルを開く。

    カーソルが文頭だったとき 数字-1 の文末
    カーソルが文末だったとき 数字+1 の文頭
    文頭=文末の場合は文頭処理優先

    想定したパターンは
        '1',,,'9','10',,,
        '001',,,'009','010',,,
    数値の文字列長さが不揃いな物は想定していない。ex., '00001', '2', '03'

*/
    var topPrev = -1;
    var yPos = document.selection.GetActivePointY( eePosLogical );
    if( yPos != 1 ){
        if( yPos != document.GetLines() )   Quit();
        topPrev = 1;
    }

    var strName = document.Name;
    var baseName = strName.match( /^(.*)\.(.*?)$/ );
    var numMatch = baseName[1].match( /^(.*?)(\d+)([^\d]*?)$/ );    // ファイル名末尾の数字
    if( numMatch.length != 4 )  Quit();
    var num = 1 * numMatch[2];      // alert( 0 + "1" );    // Jscript だと 0 + "1" -> '01'
    if( num == 0 && topPrev == -1 ) Quit();     // 0 より前はブロック
    num = String( num + topPrev );
    while( num.length < numMatch[2].length ){
        num = "0" + num;
    }

    var fileName = numMatch[1] + num + numMatch[3] + "." + baseName[2];
    var filePath = document.Path + "\\" + fileName;
    var FSO = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
    if( FSO.FileExists( filePath ) ){
        editor.OpenFile( filePath );
        editor.ExecuteCommandByID( (topPrev == -1)? 4169 : 4168 );  // EEID_BOTTOM (4169), EEID_TOP (4168)
        Quit();
    }

// 先頭の "0" を一つだけ減らして再確認
    if( num.substr(0,1) != "0" )    Quit();
    num = num.substr(1);
    fileName = numMatch[1] + num + numMatch[3]  + "." + baseName[2];
    filePath = document.Path + "\\" + fileName;
    if( FSO.FileExists( filePath ) ){
        editor.OpenFile( filePath );
        editor.ExecuteCommandByID( (topPrev == -1)? 4169 : 4168 );
    }
```

#### lljump_pre.jsee

```js
#title = "連番-1 の文書を開く"

/*

    アクティブな文書のファイル名最後の数字を1減させたファイル文末を開く。

    想定したパターンは
        '1',,,'9','10',,,
        '001',,,'009','010',,,
    数値の文字列長さが不揃いな物は想定していない。ex., '00001', '2', '03'

*/

    var strName = document.Name;
    var baseName = strName.match( /^(.*)\.(.*?)$/ );
    var numMatch = baseName[1].match( /^(.*?)(\d+)([^\d]*?)$/ );    // ファイル名末尾の数字
    if( numMatch.length != 4 )  Quit();
    var num = 1 * numMatch[2];
    if( num == 0 )  Quit();     // 0 より前はブロック
    num = String( num - 1 );
    while( num.length < numMatch[2].length ){
        num = "0" + num;
    }

    var fileName = numMatch[1] + num + numMatch[3] + "." + baseName[2];
    var filePath = document.Path + "\\" + fileName;
    var FSO = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
    if( FSO.FileExists( filePath ) ){
        editor.OpenFile( filePath );
        document.selection.EndOfDocument();
        Quit();
    }

// 先頭の "0" を一つだけ減らして再確認
    if( num.substr(0,1) != "0" )    Quit();
    num = num.substr(1);
    fileName = numMatch[1] + num + numMatch[3] + "." + baseName[2];
    filePath = document.Path + "\\" + fileName;
    if( FSO.FileExists( filePath ) ){
        editor.OpenFile( filePath );
        document.selection.EndOfDocument();
    }
```

#### lljump_succ.jsee

```js
#title = "連番+1 の文書を開く"

/*

    アクティブな文書のファイル名最後の数字を 1増させたファイル文頭を開く。

    想定したパターンは
        '1',,,'9','10',,,
        '001',,,'009','010',,,
    数値の文字列長さが不揃いな物は想定していない。ex., '00001', '2', '03'

*/

    var strName = document.Name;
    var baseName = strName.match( /^(.*)\.(.*?)$/ );
    var numMatch = baseName[1].match( /^(.*?)(\d+)([^\d]*?)$/ );    // ファイル名末尾の数字
    if( numMatch.length != 4 )  Quit();
    var num = 1 * numMatch[2];
    num = String( num + 1 );
    while( num.length < numMatch[2].length ){
        num = "0" + num;
    }

    var fileName = numMatch[1] + num + numMatch[3] + "." + baseName[2];
    var filePath = document.Path + "\\" + fileName;
    var FSO = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
    if( FSO.FileExists( filePath ) ){
        editor.OpenFile( filePath );
        document.selection.StartOfDocument();
        Quit();
    }
```

lljump_pre.jsee, lljump_succ.jsee を実行するか 、
カーソルを文末文頭へ移動させて、lljump.jsee を実行すれば期待する動作に近い応答をすると思います。
ファイル名の末尾から見て最初の数字を対象にするので '旅行1日目.txt' でも可能です。

標準では割り当てられていない Ctrl+Shift+(PageUp,PageDown) に lljump_pre.jsee, lljump_succ.jsee を割り当てると便利になるかと思います。

- 現状未対応な物
  ゼロパディング以外のパターン `"  1",," 10", "__1",,"_10"`
  全角の数字、漢字の数字、1st,2nd など

Comment: いつもコードをくわしく書いていただき、ありがとうございます。ご厚意に深謝しております。私が理想と考える動きとは少々異なりました。私の理想と考える動きは次のようなものです。最初の資料001.txtとか資料001.csvなどの開始番号をまずひとつだけEmEditorで開きます。それでマクロボタンを押すと同じフォルダにある資料001.txt～資料099.txtまで数字順に繋がって、別の結合ファイル「資料001結合.txt」の画面が開いて結合ファイルも同一フォルダに新規保存されるという仕組みです。これで実質的に最初の001.txtを開くだけで結合ファイル作成も開くことも同時に一度でできます。もしかすると上記のコードは、このようになっているのに私の使い方が間違っているのかもしれません。そのばあいは、すみません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 保存される形式は元の001番と同じ形式が理想と考えます。Shift_JIS の場合はShift_JIS で、UTF-8だった場合はUTF-8で保存される仕様です。よろしくお願いいたします。